# My IntelliJ IDEA doesn't launch and when I launch it, it just refresh

Tags: intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide, launch

I've installed IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition version 2018.3.6.

When I launch the shortcut it doesn't start and just do anything that is shown in refreshing (green circle). I've tired and I can't do anything.

I wanted to install Android Studio but my computer doesn't support it. Now, IntelliJ doesn't run too. Please help.

Comment: This needs more information. What is your OS? How did you install IntelliJ (and why this really old version?). I'd suggest re-installing via the [JetBrains Toolbox](https://www.jetbrains.com/toolbox-app/).

Comment: Also, you might get better support by directly going to [JetBrains support](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/topics/200382555-IntelliJ-IDEA-Users) and asking there.